# How to limit zoom to X-axis (horizontal zoom) in Ariutta's svgpanzoom library

Tags: javascript, svg, svgpanzoom

The examples look fantastic for pan/zoom of inline SVG at:

https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom

I'm trying to figure out how to zoom inline SVG only in the horizontal, while leaving the vertical axis static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way to zoom only on one axis. 
You can see [this thread](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom/issues/176) for the discussions about that. There is a [link to an attempt](https://github.com/jeremyVignelles/svg-pan-zoom/commit/60eb591df386952789d52e07f1595b479153cbf3) to implement that, but I don't know what's its status.